# Poloniex API using requests, returnBalances works, but returnTradeHistory does not

Tags: python, poloniex

I'm trying to access the Poloniex API using requests.

The `returnBalances` code works, but the `returnTradeHistory` code does not.

The `returnTradeHistory` is commented out in the example.

Data is returned for `returnBalances` but not for `returnTradeHistory`.

I know the whole `APIKey` and secret code is working because I am getting accurate `returnBalances` data.

**So why is `returnTradeHistory` not working?**

```
from time import time
import urllib.parse
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import json

APIKey=b"stuff goes in here"
secret=b"stuff goes in here"

url = "https://poloniex.com/tradingApi"

# this works and returns data
payload = {
    'command': 'returnBalances',
    'nonce': int(time() * 1000),
}

# this does not work and does not return data
#payload = {
#    'command': 'returnTradeHistory',
#    'currencyPair': 'BTC_MAID',
#    'nonce': int(time() * 1000),
#}

paybytes = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf8')
sign = hmac.new(secret, paybytes, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Key': APIKey,
    'Sign': sign,
}
r = requests.post(url, data=paybytes, headers=headers)
fulldata=r.content
data = json.loads(fulldata)
print(data)
```

Comment: That might have more to do with the API you're invoking than your code.  Do you get back any specific response code that isn't a 2xx?

Comment: For both I get <Response [200]> . The "returnBalances" has content in "r" but "returnTradeHistory" has no content in "r".  I strong suspect it's how I am passing the 'currencyPair' : 'BTC_MAIN' to the api.  It is a bit frustrating all the examples I find on the poloniex api do not address passing params to the api.

Comment: I got a buy to work.  Now the proud owner of 40 MAIDS. Certain commands like returnTradeHistory, return24Volume and returnTicket need to be treated differently. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official poloniex API documentation](https://poloniex.com/support/api/):

> **returnTradeHistory**
>
> Returns the past 200 trades for a given market, or up to 50,000 trades
>   **between a range specified** in UNIX timestamps by the "**start**" and "**end**"
>   GET parameters [...]

so it is required to specify the `start` and `end` parameter

e.g: `https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTradeHistory&currencyPair=BTC_NXT&start=1410158341&end=1410499372`